# PYGAME : How to collide 2 groups of sprites of 2 classes and "AttributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'rect'"

Tags: python, class, pygame, collision

I would like to collide cible and projectile, when they collide, they disapeared.To know if collision is detected i put a print. If you know the command to make the two collided ojbects disapeared it'd be cool :)

> ```py
> There is also an error :"AttributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'rect'"
> ```

Here is my code :

```
#                     --- Import des bibliothèques utilisées (dont pygame) ---
import pygame
from pygame import*
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
from random import *


#                                      --- Classe du jeu ---

class Jeux:

    def __init__(self):
        # generer notre joueur
        self.all_players = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player()
        self.all_players.add(self.player)
        # groupe de cible
        self.all_cibles = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.pressed = {}

        collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(Cible, Projectile, False)
        if collisions:
            print('collision')

#                                     --- Classe du joueur ---

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.attack = 10
        self.velocity = 7
        """self.all_players = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()"""
        self.all_cibles = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("F:/ISN/game/ressource/vaisseau1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 600

    def launch_projectile(self):
        self.all_projectiles.add(Projectile(self))

    def launch_cible(self):
        self.all_cibles.add(Cible(self))

# fonction pour aller a droite
    def move_right(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velocity

# fonction pour aller a gauche
    def move_left(self):
        self.rect.x -= self.velocity


#                                 --- Classe du projectile ---

class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player, game):
        super().__init__()
        self.velocity = 7
        self.player = player
        self.projectile = projectile
        self.image = pygame.image.load("F:/ISN/game/ressource/projectile-png-2.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (10, 20))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.all_projectiles.add(self.projectile)
        self.rect.x = player.rect.x + 59
        self.rect.y = player.rect.y

    # fonction servant à détruire le projectile quand il est hors de la fenêtre
    def remove_projectile(self):
        self.player.all_projectiles.remove(self)

    def move(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.velocity

    # vérifier si notre projectile n'est plus présent sur l'écran
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            # supprimer le projectile
            self.remove_projectile()


#                                 --- Classe de la cible ---

class Cible(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, player):
        super().__init__()
        self.game = game
        self.cible = cible
        self.image = pygame.image.load("F:/ISN/game/ressource/catalan.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (40, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.all_cibles.add(self.cible)
        self.rect.x = randint(50, 1000)
        self.rect.y = randint(0, 400)

    def remove_cible(self):
        self.player.all_cibles.remove(self)

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(Player, Projectile, False):
        print('Collide')



#                      --- Gestion des touches et de la fenêtre de jeu ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# generer la fenetre du jeu
pygame.display.set_caption("SPACE INVADERS V2")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 720))

# importer charger l'arriere plan
background = pygame.image.load("F:/ISN/game/ressource/BACKGROUND.jpg")

# charger notre jeu
game = Jeux()


running = True
# boucle tant que cette condition est vrai
while running:

    # appliquer l'arriere plan de notre jeu
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    # appliquer l'image de notre joueur sur la fenetre de jeu
    screen.blit(game.player.image, game.player.rect)

    # afficher la cible 
    game.player.all_cibles.draw(screen)

    # recuperer les projectiles du joueur
    for projectile in game.player.all_projectiles:
        projectile.move()

    # appliquer l'ensemble des images de mon groupe de projectiles
    game.player.all_projectiles.draw(screen)

    # mouvements du joueur
    if game.pressed.get(pygame.K_RIGHT) and game.player.rect.x + game.player.rect.width < screen.get_width():
        game.player.move_right()
    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_LEFT) and game.player.rect.x > 0:
        game.player.move_left()

    # mettre a jour l'ecran
    pygame.display.flip()

    # si le joueur ferme cette fenetre
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # que l'evenement est fermeture de fenetre
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            print("Fermeture du jeu")
        # detecter si un joueur lache une touche du clavier
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           game.pressed[event.key] = True
           if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
               game.player.launch_projectile()
           elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
               game.player.launch_cible()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            game.pressed[event.key] = False
```

I don't know how to do, please help me

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you are accessing `Player.rect` (player with a capital *P*) instead of `player.rect`. In other words, somewhere, you are trying to access the `.rect` attribute of the *class Player*, and not of a `Player` *instance*

Comment: I think i fixed this but now it says :``` AttributeError: type object 'Cible' has no attribute 'rect'```

Comment: Same thing, but now for `Cible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st argument to [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) has to be an instance of [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and the 2nd argument has to be an instance of [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group).
Thus `pygame.sprite.spritecollide(Cible, Projectile, False)` does not make any sense because `Cible` and `Projectile`are classes.

`self.all_cibles` and `self.all_projectiles` are instances of `pygame.sprite.Group`. A collision of Groups can be evaluated by [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). e.g:

```py
collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(
    self.all_projectiles, self.all_cibles, False, False)
```

By passing `True` to the `dokill1` respectively `dokill2` argument, the `Sprites` can be removed from all `Groups` and thus destroyed.
For instance, pass `False` to `dokill1` and `True` to `dokill2`, thus projectiles will destroy cibles:

```py
collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(
    self.all_projectiles, self.all_cibles, False, True)
```

---

If you want to do a collision test, then you have to do it in the main application loop. For instance:

```py
running = True
# boucle tant que cette condition est vrai
while running:
    # [...]

    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(game.all_projectiles, game.all_cibles, False, True)
    if collisions:
        print('collision')

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(game.player, game.all_projectiles, False):
        print('Collide')
```

---

The complete code may look as follows:

```py
#                     --- Import des bibliothèques utilisées (dont pygame) ---
import pygame
from pygame import*
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
from random import *

#                                      --- Classe du jeu ---
class Jeux:

    def __init__(self):
        # generer notre joueur
        self.all_players = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player()
        self.all_players.add(self.player)
        # groupe de cible
        self.all_cibles = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.pressed = {}

#                                     --- Classe du joueur ---
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.attack = 10
        self.velocity = 7
        """self.all_players = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()"""
        self.image = pygame.image.load("F:/ISN/game/ressource/vaisseau1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 600

    def launch_projectile(self):
        game.all_projectiles.add(Projectile(self, game))

    def launch_cible(self):
        game.all_cibles.add(Cible(self, game))

# fonction pour aller a droite
    def move_right(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velocity

# fonction pour aller a gauche
    def move_left(self):
        self.rect.x -= self.velocity


#                                 --- Classe du projectile ---
class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player, game):
        super().__init__()
        self.velocity = 7
        self.game = game
        self.player = player
        self.image = pygame.image.load("F:/ISN/game/ressource/projectile-png-2.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (10, 20))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.game.all_projectiles.add(self)
        self.rect.x = player.rect.x + 59
        self.rect.y = player.rect.y

    # fonction servant à détruire le projectile quand il est hors de la fenêtre
    def remove_projectile(self):
        self.game.all_projectiles.remove(self)

    def move(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.velocity

    # vérifier si notre projectile n'est plus présent sur l'écran
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            # supprimer le projectile
            self.remove_projectile()


#                                 --- Classe de la cible ---
class Cible(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player, game):
        super().__init__()
        self.game = game
        self.image = pygame.image.load("F:/ISN/game/ressource/catalan.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (40, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.game.all_cibles.add(self)
        self.rect.x = randint(50, 1000)
        self.rect.y = randint(0, 400)

    def remove_cible(self):
        self.game.all_cibles.remove(self)


#                      --- Gestion des touches et de la fenêtre de jeu ---
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# generer la fenetre du jeu
pygame.display.set_caption("SPACE INVADERS V2")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 720))

# importer charger l'arriere plan
background = pygame.image.load("F:/ISN/game/ressource/BACKGROUND.jpg")

# charger notre jeu
game = Jeux()


running = True
# boucle tant que cette condition est vrai
while running:

    # appliquer l'arriere plan de notre jeu
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    # appliquer l'image de notre joueur sur la fenetre de jeu
    screen.blit(game.player.image, game.player.rect)

    # afficher la cible 
    game.all_cibles.draw(screen)

    # recuperer les projectiles du joueur
    for projectile in game.all_projectiles:
        projectile.move()

    # appliquer l'ensemble des images de mon groupe de projectiles
    game.all_projectiles.draw(screen)

    # mouvements du joueur
    if game.pressed.get(pygame.K_RIGHT) and game.player.rect.x + game.player.rect.width < screen.get_width():
        game.player.move_right()
    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_LEFT) and game.player.rect.x > 0:
        game.player.move_left()

    # mettre a jour l'ecran
    pygame.display.flip()

    # si le joueur ferme cette fenetre
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # que l'evenement est fermeture de fenetre
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            print("Fermeture du jeu")
        # detecter si un joueur lache une touche du clavier
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           game.pressed[event.key] = True
           if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
               game.player.launch_projectile()
           elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
               game.player.launch_cible()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            game.pressed[event.key] = False

    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(game.all_projectiles, game.all_cibles, False, True)
    if collisions:
        print('collision')

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(game.player, game.all_projectiles, False):
        print('Collide')
```